# how can I get list of file names from website

Tags: c#

how can I get list of file names from website

Suppose I have an URL "www.demo.com/public" and in public directory I have multiple .jpg files.
So how can I get .jpg file names in list in c# from that URL

Comment: Is it your website, or some arbitrary website? If the latter, then there's no way, unless you know the API of that website and it contains a special resource that could give you such info

Comment: If you can get a webpage with all the files listed (e.g. in your browser), then you can potentially parse the given webpage to collect all the filenames

Comment: If that's an FTP directory, then you can use this protocol to get all the info about all the accessible files

Comment: You could make the folder shared and access like any other network folder.

Comment: @AlexLarionov it's something like public drive's account..how can we parse given webpage. When I go at "www.demo.com/public" i can see list of files that are .txt, .jpg etc and i want only .jpg s

Comment: @YogeshDangre press F12 in your browser on this webpage. There is an HTML representation of every component of this webpage. Navigate to a particular part where files are listed, the structure of this list is usually more or less consistent, so you can notice how exactly all filenames are stored in this HTML, use some library for your language that parses HTML and extract all the filenames in code. You'll get a list of strings, among which only take those that end at .jpg.

Comment: Try searching on google: web-scraping

Comment: @AlexLarionov okay thanks but parsing HTML is quite complicated. I got a substitution resolution for time being like saving HTML webpage as a PDF and parsing .jpg names from it.!!!